# UI/UX feature in calling app

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, ux-designer, human-interface-guideline

I have some difficulty with one UI feature. In my calling app I would like to let user to choose whom he would like to call – someone from his contact or invite someone (i.e. send him a link to join a conversation). I have the following ideas how to depict that – pic 1 & 2

[image]

Please, notice the invitation link will be provided later...after some more steps.

What do you think about them? What do you like? Maybe you have some ideas how to improve them or some other examples.

Answer (score 1):

**I would try to merge the two.** I remember LinkedIn doing so in earlier versions. I don't know if that is still true.

There is a definite benefit of merging. Your user need not remember if she has added that contact before or not. More often than not, users tend to forget who all are in their contact lists.

By merging you also reduce clutter on the screen. **User comes with a clear objective. She wants to place a call.** She searches for a contact. Your autocomplete feature will pull up the right contact or ask to follow up with an invitation.

The invite link can open a pop up or navigate the user to a different screen to do other formalities for inviting the user.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go with option 1, because when user click on the the Invite tab you can provide a link to join the conversation in the same belonging Textbox. While with option 2 you need to than open some popup or need to manage other UI to display link.

In case if invite link is directly send to the user, than go for the option 2 but the below UI will be more friendly.

[image]

Even excluding 'or' will look more decent.

Comment: Please, notice the invitation link will be provided later...after some more steps.

Comment: @Kirill, Than in that case would be better to go with option 2. Also as Alvaro mentioned you can display predefined list below the search box.

Answer (score 0):

You have something like this:

```
Friend in my list:          Search friend in list,
                            Call to friend

Friend not in my list:      Invite friend,
                            New friend added to list (confirmation),
                            Search friend in list,
                            Call to friend
```

So you could separate both actions, something similar to your option 1, **not mixing the *"call to"* and *"invite"* actions**. Also you could make a predefined list of persons (favourites, last called, alphabetical) before the user starts to type something in the search input.

```
Call to:    Search friend       or      Invite a friend
            ---
            Friend A
            Friend B
            Friend C
            ...
```

Selecting "invite a friend" will redirect the user somewhere else or show him a dialog for the invitation process.

Answer (score 0):

What about having just one field entry for name or email. Your app then validates the entry against the associated address book. If no match is found you simply offer users the opportunity to invite that user.